# Regex to check if username is valid or not

Tags: php, regex

Good morning,

I want to check if the usernames the users are picking are valid or not.
Sadly I can't find any Regex which suits my needs and writing it myself doesn't bring me far.
I hope I can get some help here. :)

> Rules:
>   3-26 Digits
>   a-z
>   A-Z
>   0-9
>   One dot allowed ( . )

Until now I have:

```
if ( !preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{3,26}$/', $joinUser) )
```

But the dot is making me problems.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 3 to 26 digits? or letters?

Comment: Would it be kosher to pre-qualify the value as having at most 1 period, then subject it to the regex above with period as a valid character?

Comment: 3-26 Digits, not only letters. :)

Comment: Not completly.
I don't care about this part:
"Underscore and dot can't be at the end or start of a username (e.g _username / username_ / .username / username.)."

And I want them to be useable only once not like in 4.
"Underscore or dot can't be used multiple times > in a row < (e.g user__name / user..name)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach with a negative lookahead:

```
'/^(?!.*[.].*[.])[A-Za-z0-9.]{3,26}$/'
```

or

```
'/^(?!.*\..*\.)[A-Za-z0-9.]{3,26}$/'
```

using escapes instead of character classes.

The negative lookahead will cause this regex not to match something with two or more periods.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out! it would match for single period or underscore, not multiple, not both. hope this helps!

```
if(preg_match('/^(?=.{3,26}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._][a-z0-9]+)?$/i', $username)) 
    echo 'Match';
echo 'Not Match';
```